# php script can't browse pages pagination not works maybe typo or variable

Tags: php, html, variables, pagination

My PHP script can't browse pages and I can't locate this problem or where the error is.
So the problem is I can't browse pages... For example, I have 19 pages, and when I click on any number to go to that page, it doesn't browse to where it is supposed to, it just stays on page one.
The file causing that, is browse.php, I added the code below.

```
// The PREVIOUS page begins at the current offset LESS the number of ROWS per page
$previous_offset = $offset - ROWS;

// The NEXT page begins at the current offset PLUS the number of ROWS per page
$next_offset = $offset + ROWS;

// format query string depending on if
// mod_rewrite is on of off
if (REWRITE_URLS == 1) {
$browse_script_name = $browse_script_name . "?offset=";
} else {
$browse_script_name = $browse_script_name . "&offset=";
}

// show the row numbers that are being viewed like this:
// "10 - 15 of 20"
$browse_info = "
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
<tr>
    <td align=\"center\" valign=\"middle\" style=\"white-space: nowrap;   
 font-weight: bold;\">Showing " . ($offset + 1) . " - " . ($row_counter + $offset) . " of $rows_found Articles</td>
   </tr>
 </table>";

 // Are there any PREVIOUS Pages?
if ($offset > 0)
{
// yes, so create a link
$browse_previous = "
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td style=\"white-space: nowrap;\"><a class=\"browse\" href=\"$browse_script_name" . $previous_offset . $browse_string . "\">&#171; Previous</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>";

} else {

// no there is no previous page so dont make a link
$browse_previous = "
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td style=\"white-space: nowrap;\">&#171; Previous</td>
    </tr>
 </table>";

 }// end if ($offset > 0)

  // are there any NEXT pages
  if ((ROWS != false) && ($rows_found > $next_offset))
 {
 // yes so create a link
 $browse_next = "
 <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td style=\"white-space: nowrap;\"><a class=\"browse\" href=\"$browse_script_name" . $next_offset . $browse_string . "\">Next &#187;</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>";

 } else {

 // no so dont create a link
 $browse_next = "
 <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td style=\"white-space: nowrap;\">Next &#187;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>";

 }// end if (($row != false) && ($rows_found > $next_offset))

  // initialize $browse_page
  $browse_page = "
  <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
<tr>
    <td>";

   // output page numbers as links
  for ($x = 0, $page = 1; $x < $rows_found; $x += ROWS, $page++)
  {  
  // is this the current page?
  if ($x < $offset || $x > ($offset + ROWS - 1))
  {
    // no, so make a link
    $browse_page .= " <a class=\"browse\" href=\"$browse_script_name" . $x . $browse_string . "\">". $page . "</a> ";

} else {

    // yes, so dont make a link
    $browse_page .= " $page ";

 }// end if ($x < $offset || $x > ($offset + ROWS - 1))

 }// end for ($x = 0, $page = 1; $x < $rows_found; $x += ROWS, $page++)
$browse_page .= "
    </td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: what is the href  value ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line is the problem?

```
"<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td style=\"white-space: nowrap;\"><a class=\"browse\" href=\"$browse_script_name" . $previous_offset . $browse_string . "\">&#171; Previous</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>";
```

I noticed you do leave your '$browse_script_name' within your quotes, then you take write the other variables outside the quotes. And you do the same thing for all the lines. Perhaps you'd look into something like this:

```
<?php
// previous code ...
$browse_previous = "<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td style=\"white-space: nowrap;\"><a class=\"browse\" href=\"" . $browse_script_name . $previous_offset . $browse_string . "\">&#171; Previous</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>";
// remaining code ...
```

Now this would be a very superficial understanding of what is going on in the backend, I am only attemping to understand the logic, if this does not have try to provide a better background of the problem you're having.